# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't detect hard disk partitions

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, installation, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit on an ASUS Laptop and wanted to install it in another one, the ASUS A55V.

After booting the laptop and setting up Windows 7 (I unfortunately cannot wipe out Windows), and creating one extra partition to install Ubuntu there, when I reboot from USB and launch Ubuntu installation, it doesn't recognize any partition on /dev/sda, but shows the whole disk as unpartitioned. I guess this is due to UEFI, but I don't know how I can make Ubuntu see the partitions created by Windows. Or any workaround for this to be able to install Ubuntu on /dev/sda.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change Hard controller mode in BIOS,may it works

Comment: Or use the GParted liveCD and boot from that to see if you can see the partitions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure what partition table layout do you have - MBR or GPT. If you have new computer with UEFI second option if more probable. Try gdisk (should be available id repo) and see if it's providing any data.